# Sessions work on one computer but not on another

Tags: php, session, internet-explorer

Several topics on sessions being lost including an extensive one on Github, but none seem to relate to why they might work on one computer but not on another.

I have 200+ users on a small management system.  Logon on is controlled by the usual username and password and on verification the user sees a welcome page for which a session is started by the usual php session_start().  This has been working on Edge, IE, Chrome and Firefox and as far as I am aware Safari, since some users are on Apple, but I don't have access to an Apple device.  I recently changed host and the new host uses LiteSpeed.

I have two users who can logon on in IE and get the welcome page (at which point the session is started) but when they request the next page, they are asked to logon on again which implies that the session has been lost. The obvious reasons of cookies/sessions being turned off have been addressed.

I can use their credentials and logon and work using IE, Edge, Firefox and Chrome on my computer.  One user can logon and work if a different browser is used. I am waiting to hear if the second user can work with a different browser.  I know there are other users working with IE without problems.

I am not sure whether the problem existed before I switched hosts and started using LiteSpeed, and that maybe just a coincidence but the problem does seem to stem form round about that time, but I'm still puzzled as to why the sessions stay put on some computers running IE but not on others.  Ideas appreciated.

Comment: Can you show any specific customisations you've made on your php.ini?

Comment: People may have problems due to moving hosts and having old cached data from the old DNS, get everyone to clear their site browser history and see if this makes the issue disappear?

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a silly question but just for sanity check... You are indeed sharing `session_start();`  on all pages correct? Each page needs this to read the stored variables associated to the session such as login authentication or what not.

Try adding this above session_start which comes from a php forum:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE')) {
    session_cache_limiter("public");
}
```

Comment: Yes, session_start() is definitely on all pages.  It's just weird that it works fine on some computers and not on others and it only seems to be IE, as far as I know, that causes a problem.

Comment: Revising answer to include a script for MSIE

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I gather it needs to go before every session_start(), so that will take a bit of organising.

Comment: yes. At least try it in two locations so you can test it on the second page to see if you are still having the issue.